# How does the "Chakra induction paper" react when someone has multiple chakra natures

Tags: naruto, boruto

A Chakra induction paper can be used to detect an individuals Chakra affinity. In cases **where a person is born with affinity to multiple Chakra Natures**, do all those characteristics happen simultaneously to the "induction paper"? Or does the paper react only to an individuals strongest Chakra Nature. If so then ***how do Jonin level Shinobi check for their secondary Chakra Natures*** or decide what other elements would be a good fit for them.

Comment: Canon doesn't say much, but I've seen a lot of fanfiction where the paper just reacts to all the natures. e.g. from ch. 16 of [this cracky fanfic](https://archiveofourown.org/works/3334637/chapters/7291826): `Sakura's paper moistened, then crumbled. Sasuke's moistened, crinkled, split in half, crumbled, and burned. Naruto's did nothing for a second. Then, just when Kakashi was about to ask if the blond was sure he was following the instructions correctly, the slip of paper flashed, shining like a thousand watt lightbulb in the boy's hand, before exploding into a shower of multicolored sparks.`

Answer (score 2):

**In cases where a person is born with affinity to multiple Chakra Natures, do all those characteristics happen simultaneously to the "induction paper"?** It is not known or rather, it was never shown in the manga as far as I know. In **Chapter 315**, it was not stated whether the litmus paper test is applicable to people using two nature types. However, it is implied that any person only has one nature affinity, regardless if they have Kekkei Genkai or not, or if they can use multiple natures. As far as I know, *there were no people mentioned that have multiple chakra nature affinities, only those who can wield multiple ones*. The existence of the litmus paper test in itself is proof that people only have one nature affinity. They would've thought of a way for another test if ever there was a person with two nature affinities. So yes, *the paper reacts only to an individual's strongest chakra nature or the nature which he/she has a strong affinity towards*.

**How do Jonin level Shinobi check for their secondary Chakra Natures or decide what other elements would be a good fit for them?** Again, this was never stated nor elaborated in **Chapter 316** so we can only guess. However, if I were to guess, it was never the case that they have to find out their second strongest affinity to another nature but rather, *they would probably choose a second nature to master that would give them an advantage*, especially on situational cases. Also, they would probably master a secondary nature that is strong against a nature they are weak on. For example, if one has an affinity towards or if they have their strongest jutsu in Fire Release, they would probably master Earth Release to counteract against Water Release. Or *it would be possible that they will just master any element they can*. The only thing that can be said is that *we can never truly say that a certain chakra nature is a good or bad fit to another certain chakra nature, or that you shouldn't master a certain nature if you possess or have an affinity towards another certain nature* since it depends on many things.

Apparently, you can master all releases through training. Examples of shinobi who did so are [Hashirama Senju, Tobirama Senju, Hiruzen Sarutobi, Orochimaru and Mū](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation#Affinity). Other possible ways to acquire master all chakra nature include:

- Possession of the [Rinnegan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan) to shorten the learning process.
- Acquiring the [Six Paths Senjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_Senjutsu) and [Truth-Seeking Balls](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Truth-Seeking_Ball).
- Possession of the [Bashōsen](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Bash%C5%8Dsen) allows any shinobi the usage of all five
  natures.
- Using [Earth Grudge Fear](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Grudge_Fear) to gather hearts with other chakra natures (Kakuzu)

Comment: Yup. In short, it's implied that everyone only has one affinity. This just means that it's the chakra nature that's easiest for a shinobi to learn. Lots of shinobi master natures outside of their affinity, but this is not the same as their affinity.

Comment: I think thats what is kinda confusing me @ahiijny lets take Boruto for example, he is stated to have 3 chakra natures.  Does he have affinity to all 3 elements, if not then what is his main affinity? cause I actually developed this question when i was thinking what would happen if Boruto used the "Chakra induction paper".  And note that he never had difficulty in mastering wind or lightning, which lead me to think that he was born with an affinity to multiple nature types.

Comment: Also, logically speaking, a person with a kekkai genkai ability to form tetiary releases, e.g wood or ice can use 2 elements simulteneously to create something new. In such cases don't they have affinity to multiple elements?

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin To use an analogy, I'd imagine that "affinity" is sort of similar to first-past-the-post voting. A shinobi's chakra affinity is like the candidate who gets the most votes. That's just by definition; affinity is the chakra nature that a shinobi would find easiest to use. But this doesn't say anything about how wide the gap is. e.g. it could be that a shinobi finds two natures pretty easy to use, but it's just that one nature is just slightly easier to use than the other one (e.g. like the winner winning by only 1 vote). There would still only be one winner.

Comment: And of course, like the ["nauseated" vs. "nauseous"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/125961) distinction, lots of people in practice use words in ways that the original definers didn't intend, and language evolves. People these days seem to tend to also use affinity to mean "well they're pretty good with that nature". This is unlike chakra paper, which allegedly only responds only the #1 strongest nature. As for kekkai genkai, they're weird edge cases, so I'm not sure about those.

Comment: As for Boruto, he can use those 3 elements pretty easily, so it's not clear which element is his affinity. Some have speculated that it's lightning release because it was so easy for him that he added it to his rasengan without thinking, but apparently this was wind release in the novels, which is pretty confusing :/

Comment: I'd like to add, that Chakra strength/weakness forms a circle. Having a affinity to one chakra nature, makes it easier for you to learn it. hte second chakra nature a jonin must be able to controle is often a neighbor of their affinity, since that is easier for them to learn too because its next to the affinity one.